# How to find a word in a string using a pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of `strings` and I would like to check if in this string I have a specific `word`, if yes I copy it to a list. This word need to be before a `= {`

For example if I have, as `strings`:

```
TOTO_TEST = {0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}
```

And as `word`:

```
TOTO
```

I already tried this:

```
if fnmatch.filter(strings, word + '* = {')
```

This will not find my `string`. It will only works if the `string` is :

```
TEST_TOTO = {0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with my *fnmatch* please?
BTW I'm really open for another way to do it!

Comment: Would a simple `if word == strings.partition(' = {')[0]` suffice?

Comment: @anubhava Sorry I'm a bit new to Python, you mean to put this in a fnmatch.filter ?

Comment: Are you filtering file names? fnmatch is really for Unix filename matching https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html You probably want to use re instead https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

strings = 'TOTO_TEST = {0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}'
word = 'TOTO'

if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'(?=.*=\s*{)', strings, re.I):
    print 'yes'
```

You can do something like this.Here through the use `lookahead` we make sure after the word we have `={` somewhere in the string.

Comment: Is this one would work with this?


` = {`
`={`
`= {`
and so on. BTW can you explain this regex as I'm not proficient on that. Thanks

Comment: for example:

    "TOTO_TEST = {0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}"
    "TOTO_TEST= {0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}"
    "TOTO_TEST ={0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}"
    "TOTO_TEST={0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}"

I mean the space around the equal sign

Comment: Ok thanks, let me verify this on my application and if every thing is ok I will accept your answer ;)

Comment: @vks2 is it possible to have `word` case incensitive ?

Comment: Great! I check it within an hour and accept your answer

Comment: I think @VivienG wants `^` instead of `\b`. That is, he wants to match at the beginning of the line, not an arbitrary position. (This is just a guess.)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini not he just wants that word should be before `={`.

Comment: @vks is right I want to get variables receiving value in tons of c/java code files

Comment: Thanks @vks. I'm amazed!

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import re
>>> myList = []
>>> myStr = "TOTO_TEST = {0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}"
>>> match = re.search(r"(TOTO)", myStr.split("=")[0], re.S)
>>> if match:
        myList.append(match.group(1))
>>> myList
```

OUTPUT:
['TOTO']

Comment: Definitely not what I want, check the question.