# How to get multiline strings within accolade (or quotation mark) in python?

Tags: python, regex

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011882/how-to-find-a-word-in-a-string-using-a-pattern-in-python) I would like to know how to get multiline strings within accolade or quotation mark.
Here an example of `test.txt` file:

```
TOTO_TEST = {
0x68,
0x65,
0x6c,
0x6c,
0x6f
}
```

Here is my python example code:

```
import re

word = 'TOTO'

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for strings in lines:
    if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'(?=.*=\s*{)', strings, re.I):
        print (strings)
```

This will output:

```
TOTO_TEST = {
```

And I would like an output like this:

```
TOTO_TEST = {0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f}
```

EDIT:
That's just an example to summarize my project. I parse tons of C/Java source code to find variables that are initialized. Sometimes var in Java are mulitilines like that:

```
private final String TOTO_TEST = {
0x68,
0x65,
0x6c,
0x6c,
0x6f
}
```

Can someone have an idea of how to achieve that using `re.search`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with regex? Your text file looks like valid Python, so why not simply rename it, `import` it and `print TOTO_TEST`?

Comment: Please take a look at the `EDIT` instead of wanting to close that question.

Comment: You need `re.DOTALL` to make `.` include newlines, and need to capture up to the closing `}`.

Comment: "Here is my python example code: [...] This will output: `TOTO_TEST = {`". Does it output that? It looks to me like it would only print "yes" or nothing. Are you sure that's the code you're running?

Comment: Sorry I copy/paste roughtly my code, I update it quickly to something more understandable

Comment: Please give a [mcve] - for example, is the file handling relevant? It requires other users to create and read a file - if you can provide a string instead it's easier to copy and paste.

Comment: This is now an MCVE that you will be able to understand.